# Automatically accept shared folder invites in Dropbox with core API

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm using the Dropbox core API.  Is there a way, via the API, to accept an invite to a shared folder, or is there a setting I can use that will automagically accept any folder shared with my account.

Answer (score 0):

No, the API doesn't currently offer any calls for managing shared folders, so you can't use it to programmatically accept shared folder invitations.

There also isn't a setting for automatically accepting shared folder invitations.

Comment: New: API v2 does have API calls for managing with shared folders: https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/11/dropbox-api-v2-launches-today/

Comment: The API v2 allows to work with your shares but not accept invitations from other users sharing folder with you. That will be a great feature.

Comment: @EricSonaron You can do that using /2/sharing/mount_folder for the invited user: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-mount_folder